# CruiseControl with static website?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I maintain a classic asp web application, and I'd like to try to automate some of the merging to and from branches using CruiseControl (CruiseControl.net specifically). But I don't have any use for a build tool. Basically I would want a commit on /trunk to automagically get merged to a bunch of feature branches that would exist as CC projects.

Is this possible/recommended or is there an easier way to do this?

Some parts of the repository do contain VB6 or .NET code, so I would like to be able to automate builds to those parts in the future, but for the time being I would just basically be using it to automate keeping my static website clean.

Comment: Normally feature branches merge into a release and are short lived, can you explain why your setup appears to be inverted?

Comment: That's still the case with my setup. But there are more feature branches than developers, and due to enterprise practices "short lived" is not always the case, so some tool to semi-automate the merge process would help.

Comment: Would it be better to build the contents of your feature branches without merging them? You can then create and dispose of projects as feature breaches come and go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the normal responsibility of CruiseControl to affect source control, short of tagging commits. You could have another, say `release`, branch that CruiseControl monitors. The merging can then be done manually to this branch as required - resolving any merge conflicts at point of merge. CruiseControl would then just 'build' these merge commits.

CruiseControl is a basically a tool for executing commands in a given order based on a trigger. In your case a `SourceControlTrigger`.

You can setup CruiseControl to execute msbuild, or not, as required.

As you are trying to deploy/package a classic asp site, I guess you only need to copy/zip the source files and deploy them to your web server. This can be achieved as so:

1. Use nant to copy, and zip, your source files, execute it via an `nant` task
2. use curl, executed via an `exec` task to send the zip file via http(s)

If required you can preceded this with an `msbuild` task to build your .net projects.

Comment: Its worth adding that this is a very simplified description of what CruiseControl is, and can do

Comment: Thanks. What I have is several feature branches that I need to update every time the release branch is updated to keep them in sync instead of having to do this just at the end of the branch's lifetime.

Comment: CruiseControl is not designed to manage this setup. What would happen if there were merge conflicts between the release and feature branches? It would not be able to solve them automatically.

Comment: I figured I would get an email when there were conflicts and then I would know I had to resolve manually.

Comment: Don't forget the purpose of CruiseControl. CruiseControl is a build server, its meant to take a series of commits and build them into something which can be run, installed or deployed. Merging is out of its remit

Comment: I think I can probably use Subversion to do some of what I want, such as creating patches for the commits as they are done, and then sending those to an email list. "Here try this patch on your branch if you want, or not whatever." Maybe that is safer.